# Value of type '(CreateCompanyTableViewController) -> () -> CreateCompanyTableViewController' has no member 'newStakeholders'?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

I have created a new Datasource for my dynamic UITable "NewUser List" Embed nn static view cell. my problem with  `var dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)`
give me this error

> Value of type '(CreateCompanyTableViewController) -> () ->
> CreateCompanyTableViewController' has no member 'newStakeholders'

```
class CreateCompanyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblNumberOfUser: UILabel!
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder] = []
    
    @IBOutlet weak var companyUsersTableView: UITableView!
    var dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"
        companyUsersTableView.dataSource = dataSource
        companyUsersTableView.delegate = dataSource as! UITableViewDelegate
    }
}

class NewUserDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    // We keep this public and mutable, to enable our data
    // source to be updated as new data comes in.
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]

    init(newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]) {
        self.newStakeholders = newStakeholders
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newStakeholders.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let stakeholders = newStakeholders[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "newUserTableViewCell",
            for: indexPath
        ) as! NewUserTableViewCell

        

        cell.lblUsername.text  = stakeholders.fullName
        cell.lblEmail.text = stakeholders.emailAddress

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `self` is not yet initialized/available to fetch the  `newStakeholders` variable. Does doing this assignment on `viewDidLoad` triggers the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that line you are using `self` outside of a method.

Move that line to `viewDidLoad()` or to a new `init` method.